# Mysql memory usage and processes

Tags: memory, centos, mysql

I found out that mysql (on Centos7) is taking up more and more memory, and from htop I see a single process with many threads, and my memory being ~550M/3G:

```
   18895 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18896 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.63 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18897 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.65 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18898 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.64 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18899 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.43 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18900 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.73 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18901 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.40 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18902 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.67 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18903 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:05.11 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18904 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.38 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18905 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.86 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18906 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.17 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18908 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:03.69 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18909 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.33 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18910 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.67 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18911 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:04.85 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18912 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18913 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18914 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18915 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18916 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18917 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.35 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18918 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.67 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18919 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18920 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18921 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18923 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  0:00.01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables
    18894 mysql      20   0 1157M  173M  6928 S  0.0  6.1  1:05.88
```

From what I understood this processes are all in buffer, as seems also from free:

```
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2845         402          92         154        2350        2110
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

I already tried to tweak mysql /etc/my.cnf file this way, but I saw little improvement:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

join_buffer_size = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
max-connections=20

symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I'm confused as of why htop (and also Proxmox memory monitoring) report this kind of usage, while free shows more than 2G available:

```
    Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||557M/2.78G]
```

Any advice or explanation about this?
Thank in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual memory used by mysqld is 173MB, which is about right with the configuration you pasted. Htop shows all threads separately, even though their memory is in fact shared.

Use top for a more intuitive representation.

Comment: Ok, so the consumption shown by htop (and registered by Proxmox) actually is:

`total  2845 - buff/cache 2350 = ~500MB left`

And the memory is only cached, not actually used? How can I find out which processes are taking up this buffered/cached memory=

Comment: Buffers / cache are not used by processes, they are used by the kernel. Kernel will use any and all free memory available (i.e. anything not uses by other processes) and use it for caching. This is normal behaviour. Under memory pressure (i.e. if something asks to allocate more memory), kernel will throw away the cache blocks it deems least useful (or swap something out to disk) in order to free up memory for the process that requested more memory.

Comment: Ok, so I have no mean to check _what_ is stored as cache, to optimize memory usage?
Is there a way to set until which percentage system can use free memory to cache datas, like 90%, or is it all done automatically?

Comment: The kernel will use all otherwise unused memory for caching and let it go or swap things out if something else requests more memory. There is no meaningful adjustment that can be made nor should there ever be any reason to.